# Inputting a string

Tags: visual-c++

Can't compile something as simple as this, yet when I change the variable type from
string to int, it compiles and runs fine. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main() 
{
    string x;
    cin>>x;

}
```

Comment: "It doesn't compile" is about as undescriptive as you can get. *Why* doesn't it compile? If you get an error, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
#include <string>
```

To get std::string in your application.

Comment: Cool thanks. I thought "using namespace std" was sufficient. Why isn't it?

Comment: Because "using namespace std;" only brings *defined* symbols in the std namespace into the global namespace. Without including the header, the symbol "string" isn't defined anywhere. Once you've included the header, it is defined, and you can reference the symbol as std::string, or as string, if you have a proper using statement.